# How can I assign a keyboard shortcut to the 'clear' option in the messaging menu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, messaging-menu

Say I get a new email, I get a notify osd message indicating subject and sender, and the messaging menu envelope turns blue. To clear the blue indicator, I usually click on the blue envelope, and select 'clear' - the last option in that menu. I would prefer to use a shortcut for doing this. Maybe a command in CCMS - but what would be the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (tested only in 12.04):

1. Open keyboard settings through the dash
2. Go to the shortcuts tab
3. Add a custom shortcut for this command: `gdbus call --session --dest com.canonical.indicator.messages --object-path /com/canonical/indicator/messages/service --method com.canonical.indicator.messages.service.ClearAttention`
4. Click on the text "Disabled" and press your desired keys

Comment: doesn't seem to work in 13.10. Any ideas?