# What is the terminal command to clear the message menu?

Tags: 13.10, shortcut-keys, dconf, gestures, indicator-message

I would like to associate a keyboard shortcut or an Easystroke gesture to the action of clearing my message menu (i.e., the end result should be equivalent to clicking the envelope icon and then "Clear"). I've found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/146719/48105) the following command that should have done it:

```
gdbus call --session --dest com.canonical.indicator.messages --object-path /com/canonical/indicator/messages/service --method com.canonical.indicator.messages.service.ClearAttention
```

However, this doesn't seem to work on 13.10. Running it through a terminal gives me the following error:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'ClearAttention'
```

My dconf has `com.canonical.indicator.messages`, but nothing but an "applications" entry in there. How can I make this work?

Comment: reboot and try  once

Comment: Didn't work. But why should it?

Comment: i have seen some bugs related to "Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method/inerface"  that are fixed by soft restart , and upgrading some packages like gnome with some others, but i am not suggesting you to do so ,because i have not tried it . So it would be better to wait for correct and efficient answer.

Comment: Ok, now I see. It was worth the shot, anyway. Thanks for the exaplanation and effort.